# Getting lightbox to work on an iPad offline in GoodReader

Tags: html, lightbox, offline, lightbox2

Has anyone managed to get a website using lightbox working offline using GoodReader or any other offline method?

I've built a fairly simple website with images/videos using gallery with thumbnails and lightbox to view images full size. Works fine on my PC. When I transfer the files to the iPad, I can't get the images to come up full size. The pop-up just shows a spinner.

iPad running latest version, 9.2.1
GoodReader App, see http://www.goodreader.com/

Any suggestions on what could be the issue? Or a better way to view my Gallery/Video website from a thumbnail to full size, offline, on an iPad.

The purpose of the website is to demo videos/image when we have no internet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.